# Javascript - Error Message : db.collection is not a function && How to check whether the write batch whether successfully upload the data to firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
        // Get a new write batch
        const batch = writeBatch(db);

        var TransactionRecordRef = db.collection("TopUpRecord").doc();
        batch.set(TransactionRecordRef, {
            Amount: FinalTopUpAmount,
            DateTime: serverTimestamp(),
            StudentID: StudentID,
        });
               

        var TopUptoUserRef = db.collection("user").doc(UserID);
        batch.update(TopUptoUserRef, { "studentAmount": UserTotalAmount });

        batch.commit();
```

Hi, the above is my code that needs to use write batch to create a new document on TopUpRecord and update the user's amount. Now I have two questions that I need to ask one is how can I know whether the batch successfully updates the record to the firestorm and I also found that my above code has an error which "db. the collection is not a function" Is anyone why this issue happened?

Comment: db.collection not a function means your firebase library is not loaded. order of operation matters. load the js library first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the v8-and-before namespaced syntax (`db.collection("TopUpRecord").doc()`) with the v9-and-up modular syntax (`writeBatch(db)`), which isn't possible.

In the modular syntax, that line would be:

```
const TransactionRecordRef = doc(collection(db, "TopUpRecord"));
```

Also see the v9 examples in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_7), and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).